# Is there a way to know which camera captured images?

Tags: metadata, camera, exiftool

I am a medical researcher, doing research on some medical images. I have some JPEG images, and for a study, I need to include the information on the camera type used to capture those images.

Is that information is stored in image meta-data anywhere, and if yes, then how can I access it?

Also, I can't consult the photographers who captured those images because I don't have that information.

Actually, we are submitting some information to FDA so they require the type of camera on which the algorithm are tested upon. I used `exiftool` and sadly, the image doesn't carry the camera information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images might or might not indicate a camera in Exif metadata. The software [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org) can be used to check.

However, Exif data can be added or removed arbitrarily anywhere in the chain of control for an image.

This means the value of a camera or anything else in the metadata depends on what it means to know something in your specific context. Sometimes it might be ok to trust it. Sometimes it might not.

Generally if which camera really matters, then there’s less reason to trust the Exif data without a clear “chain of custody.”

If it doesn’t really matter, then it is simply a matter of context norms. What is a reasonable basis for including a fallible claim as to camera.

Comment: Actually, we are submitting some information to FDA so they require the type of camera on which the algorithm are tested upon. I used EXIF tool and sadly, the image doesn't carry the camera information. https://imgur.com/xezmjmI

Comment: Social media sites usually strip away all metadata, so the closer to the source you can get your images, the better.

Comment: You can try a google image search to find another version of the image which may have the exif intact.